# Why is a destructor not called when I click the close button on the console?

Tags: c++, windows-7, destructor, terminate

I have a command line application on Windows 7. It consists mainly of an endless loop. When I click on the close button of the command-line console window, it seems to be killed instantly. However, I close an SQLite database connection in the destructor, and so I am afraid that the databse might be corrupted. Even if not, I'd like to be able to properly terminate my object (maybe by writing something to a file, logging, etc.).

Can I somehow make sure that my destructor is called? What exactly happens if I close the window? Is there a "softer" way to close a program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A console application doesn't have a message loop where you're asked to quit however Windows gives you ability to register a function to receive *some* *notifications* you may need to handle. One of them is the *closing* notification.

First of all declare a function that Windows will call for this purpose with prototype given by [HandlerRoutine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683242(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
BOOL WINAPI ConsoleHandlerRoutine(DWORD dwCtrlType) {
    if (CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT == dwCtrlType) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Now register that function, using [SetControlCtrlHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016(v=vs.85).aspx), before you start your loop:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (FALSE == SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleHandlerRoutine, TRUE)) {
        // Cannot register your handler? Check GetLastError()
    }

    while (true)
    {
        // This is your loop
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That's done. You can explicitly delete objects you want to dispose or simply set a flag that will break your infinite loop.

Note that you will receive more events (Windows shutdown `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT`, user log-off `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT`, user break `CTRL_C_EVENT`, closing `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`), handle what you need/want.

Comment: ... actually I'm not sure you can set a flag, don't you have to complete your cleanup before exiting ConsoleHandlerRoutine?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes. If a `Handler` returns TRUE, the process terminates immediately. If it returns FALSE, the next registered `Handler` is called, and so on until one returns `TRUE` or the default `Handler` is reached, in either case the process terminates. And you have to take into account that the `Handler` is called in the context of its own thread, so make sure its code is thread-safe.

Comment: I guess in many cases it works out simplest for the handler routine to set a flag and then just sleep until the main thread terminates the process.

Comment: I as Yoda felt. That day.